# Installing Spotify via 32 bit lubuntu, processor supports 64 bit. Is it possible to get it to work?

Tags: ati, lubuntu, 32-bit, spotify

I'm running a laptop that has the ability to run 64 bit (It's dual-booting 32 bit Lubuntu and 64 bit Vista, reason being is it has a mere 2 GB ram) and I'm attempting to install Spotify. My machine is and amd/ati laptop, HP Pavilion Dv4. Thanks to a related askubuntu post, I discovered that Spotify (may?) only be for 64 bit versions. (At least, their `spotify linux preview`) and I'm attempting to install it on my Lubuntu OS.
It's spitting back the `E: Unable to locate package spotify-client` error at me.

It's worth noting that the machine cannot run Ubuntu due to a hardware issue with the Unity plugin, if that affects anything.

Is there a way to get Spotify working on this machine? Please fill me in with details, or instructions.

Thanks in advance for all the help! :)

Comment: Install a 64bit OS, there really is no excuse.

Comment: It is correct that there is currently no 32-bit version of Spotify for Linux. However, on a [Spotify community page](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Help-Desktop-Linux-Windows-Web/Spotify-0-9-4-for-32-bit-Linux/td-p/1130452), I found a [link to an older 32-bit version](https://mega.co.nz/#!VwFGkRbT!-XRVxy1aPDjaAjYzjBUDmSP05v5Nqwyp47rVsuQHw0c). Download it while you can!

Comment: Thank you Jos, I downloaded and installed the package! I'm still interested in a legit workaround though, for any future machines I might send down the linux path. (I'm actually about to build a desktop that will dual Win7/Linux.) Is there any such work around? Or will I just have to keep that download on a flash drive?

Comment: As long as your future systems are 64-bits, you will have no problems installing Spotify on them. The "Linux Preview" is actually a very decent application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it's not possible to run a 64 bit binary on a 32 bit system. However, a 32 bit build is coming soon, most likely with the next public beta. So just hang on! ;-)